# Pass BarEntry through intent

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

I'm using BarEntry in a service and I need to push yvalues through an intent to a fragment. Since BarEntry don't implements Parcelable I don't know how can I handle this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use extras to send the necessary info... This gets messy if you need multiple BarEntry's.

This is the sender side:

```
Intent inten = new Intent(context, Main.class);
intent.putExtra("value", 23);
intent.putExtra("index", 1);
```

Receiving side:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Float value = bundle.getFloat("value");
int index = bundle.getInt("index");
BarEntry barEntry = new BarEntry(value, index);
```